# Find row with longest string in R

Tags: r, string, nchar

I have this dataframe

```
DF    
     V1      
1.   123     
2.   12      
3.   12345
```

when I use the code

```
max(nchar(DF$V1))
```

I get

```
[1] 5
```

But I would like to know which row has the longest string, something like

```
[3]
```

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
which.max(nchar(DF$V1))
```

or `which(nchar(DF$V1) == max(nchar(DF$V1)))`?

Comment: which.max(nchar(DF$V1)) works!!!! many many thanks